# Can't get endpoints with external IP - Google Cloud Plataform (GCP) and OpenStack RDO

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openstack, rdo

In a GCP console, I have installed OpenStack with RDO following this tutorial - https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/.

I want to access it from others networks. But I cannot even access dashboard from my VM console.
If I hit `curl -v [internal_ip]/dashboard`, I get the correct response. But if I hit `curl -v [external_ip]/dashboard`, I can't get anything:

```
Failed connect to [external_ip]:80; Connection timed out
```

If I don't even can access external IP with VM console, so I absolutely cannot access from my machine, which is my goal.

Wy do I cant get dashboard with my GCP VM using external IP?

Comment: Are you running on Google Compute Engine? Did you enable the firewall for port 80?

Comment: Yes, Compute Engine! I don't know if it is enabled. It is default firewall settings. I'll take a look right now.

Comment: You can edit your Compute Engine instance. Then scroll down and enable `http`. You must shutdown the instance first.

Comment: It worked, just had to add that. Thank @JohnHanley!

Comment: @JohnHanley do you know how can I access that dashboard from other network? I tried adding `ServerAlias internal_ip external_ip` to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-horizon_vhost.conf` and enabled http and https options to VM firewall. Sorry if I should not ask this in this Question Page.

Comment: Create a new question with details. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with ServerAlias - explain in your new question. Let me know the new question url by commenting here.

Comment: Oh, actually, I restarted the VM and now Im able to hit dashboard from my machine. Sorry for the last comment, and thank you.